# Rewrite rules index.php?key=value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have links that look like this:

```
http://localhost/account/index.php?key=changepassword
http://localhost/account/index.php?key=changeemail

http://localhost/library/index.php?key=nemesis
http://localhost/library/index.php?key=books
```

How could I rewrite them to:

```
http://localhost/account/changepassword
http://localhost/account/changeemail

http://localhost/library/nemesis
http://localhost/library/books
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(account)/(.+?)/?$ /$1/index.php?key=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(library)/(.+?)/?$ /$1/index.php?key=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```